# How to put some variables to only some specific views?

Tags: php, laravel

I found in documentation that something similar can be done

But for all views

By putting in AppServiceProvider or other own ServiceProvider something like

`View::share('key', 'value');`

But how to share data only with `some specific` views?

Not all. Not one. But some views? Views listed im array or something that I want it to share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I usually set up this kind of situation

In AppServiceProvider

```
public function boot()
{
      View::composer(
        ['home', 'profile.edit', 'projects.create'], // array of views
        function($view){
          $foo = \App\Foo::where('active', 1)->get();
          $bar = \App\Bar::all();
          $view->with(compact('foo', 'bar'));
        }
      );
}
```

Then in the views I passed to the array,I can reference my variables:

```
@foreach($foo as $item) :

@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

Use view composer.

> You may attach a view composer to multiple views at once by passing an array of views as the first argument to the composer method

```
View::composer(
    ['profile', 'dashboard'],
    'App\Http\ViewComposers\MyViewComposer'
);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#view-composers